# Stitch images and data from coupled microscopy/spectroscopy into panoramic in Photoshop or R

Tags: javascript, r, raster, photoshop, extendscript

I have a set of images and X-ray data generated from coupled scanning electron microscopy and energy dispersive spectroscopy. Here's my problem:

I imaged transects of a rock surface like this (purple box outlines transect region):

[image]

I wanted really high resolution, so I did this using 7 images at 3000X magnification and stitched them together with the photomerge script in Photoshop. Here's an example of an individual image:

[image]

And its position in the photomerged image transect:

[image]

At each of these 7 locations, I also collected X-ray data that generates an element map for each element detected and writes this to a TIFF. I want to also stitch together each element map TIFF so I can overlay it on the merged transect image of the rock. This is the result I want:

[image]

The problem is that the element maps don't have enough features in them to be able to stitch them together with photomerge. It's basically binary - if an element is detected, the pixel is some color (like red for iron or yellow for sulfur in my example images), or black if the element is not detected. You can see there are large portions of the element maps that are mostly black.

I now have ~20 transects x 7 images each x ~10 elements  which results in ~1400 images that need to be put together, hence the need for automation.

My idea was to stitch together the rock images with photomerge. The output of photomerge is a smart object where each image is a layer. Then, I would use a script to get the top left corner coordinates, the width, and height for each of the 7 images in the photomerged image object. I would then place and assign these properties to each of the corresponding element maps for the 7 images to generate the "merged" element maps to overlay on the image. I tried to work on this myself but I'm not proficient in javascript and couldn't wrap my head around the Photoshop API.

I uploaded an example dataset on Github [here](https://github.com/CaitlinCasar/dataStitcher/tree/master/example_dataset). The 7 transect positions are from left to right: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. There are images of the rock and subdirectories with element data for each position.

Comment: Hi @Caitlin, I don't quite understand what exactly you need as the result? A Photoshop file with all layers? Or a set of exported images (with each image positioned at the correct location)?

Comment: @Caitlin LGTM!!

Comment: Hi @mdomino , thanks for your comment and sorry I didn't make that clear! I would like a Photoshop file with all the layers with each image positioned at the correct location. I've been manually typing in the coordinates etc for each element image to match the coordinates of the rock images and then making groups from the layers, i.e. I have a group of iron (Fe)  images, a group of sulfur (S) images, and a group of rock images. Let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: Ok, just wanted to ask, because someone might know of a way to achieve this without Photoshop. But if you need all the files in Photoshop at the end, it has to be done in Photoshop of course. Having written a lot of ExtendScript scripts in the past, I have to say what you are asking is probably to big of a task to be solved here on Stack Overflow. You are basically asking for an entire script that usually would require to hire someone for you. As you will need to load files by name, arrange them on the correct layers, position them by coordinates and so on. This is quite involved.

Comment: @mdomino ah I was hoping for a photoshop file output for convenience but exported images would definitely work as well!

Comment: Here's another blog post about StackOverflow that, sadly, compares it to the [Stanford prison experiment](https://yihui.org/en/2017/12/so-bounties/). @Caitlin it sounds like you're looking specifically and only for Photoshop script solutions to this problem?

Comment: Thank you @Codebling ! The reason I want to use Photoshop is for the photomerge function because I can merge my images into a panoramic. All I really need is the XY coordinates from the layers produced by that function, as in: https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/get-x-y-position-and-width-height-of-the-transform-box-of-a-layer-not-chopped-off-bounds/m-p/10986174?page=1#M315167 However, when I try to run that script I get an error which you can see in my comment on that link. Otherwise, I have a workaround in R for the rest!

Comment: Perhaps @mdomino knows why this Photoshop script throws an error? I put the error issue in the comment at the bottom of the page here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/get-x-y-position-and-width-height-of-the-transform-box-of-a-layer-not-chopped-off-bounds/m-p/10986174?page=1#M315167

Comment: @Caitlin I understand, but if someone had another alternative method of merging the layers, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Codebling definitely! I tried messing around with OpenCV in Python and found a plugin for ImageJ but the download link was dead. Apparently there's no way to do it in R, I searched the internet high and low! But I was able to reproduce the panorama in R from the images by converting them to raster and then merging the rasters with manually assigned coordinates that I got from Photoshop. It would be great to get away from Photoshop entirely!

Comment: I added my script using my example dataset in my github repo here: https://github.com/CaitlinCasar/dataStitcher

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @greg-tumolo I did the panorama stitching in Photoshop using the SEM images, then got the coordinates for each image in the panorama. I then used these coordinates to stitch the corresponding element images into panoramic rasters in R, then stacked those into raster bricks. Would love to hear your ideas if you know how to stitch images into panoramas in R!

Comment: Yes, the coupled SEM/element images were collected from the exact same field of view. And yes, the adjacent images are shifted usually in both the X and Y directions. Due to sample drift at that magnification I was unable to shift in only the X or Y directions in most cases.

Comment: Oops...I tried to delete/repost my previous comment with "10" (elements) instead of "3" and lost it.  You wrote "I then used these coordinates to stitch the corresponding element images into panoramic rasters in R...".  So, do not you already know how to stitch images into panoramas in R?

Comment: Correct, I had to do the panoramic stitching of the SEM images in Photoshop using the photomerge function. I couldn't find any packages for doing this in R, and writing that from scratch in R would have cost me too much time.

Comment: As I reread these comments, I noticed my answer does not satisfy your want.  I have implemented an alternative to photomerge; however, the alternative is probably much too slow.  How much time does photomerge take to merge 7 SEM photos?

Comment: Photomerge on 7 SEM images takes under 1 minute. The process of stitching the corresponding rasterized element images into panoramic rasters in R and then combining them into a raster brick takes maybe 10 minutes for a given set of SEM/element images. How long did your script take to run?

Comment: Now, it takes ~8 minutes with OVERLAP = 1.0 (as in my answer code).  If you reduce OVERLAP to say, 0.5, it will run faster; however, you will introduce an(other) failure mode: As can be seen in the example output (at the bottom of my answer), some images overlap by more than 40%!

Comment: will test on my end asap! thanks a ton for tackling this! :D

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know, but you can see my solution here: https://github.com/CaitlinCasar/dataStitcher/blob/master/dataStitchR.R

Comment: I hoped someone would translate my code from JavaScript to R for you.  Alas!  Did you test my code as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice to do this entirely in a Photoshop script or entirely in R, but I have a working solution that uses both. I manually pulled XY coords from the bottom left corner of each layer in the photomerge output from Photoshop and assigned them to rasterized images in R:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#Caitlin Casar
#github.com/caitlincasar
#19 March 2020
#DataStitchR stitches panoramic images of SEM images coupled to x-ray energy dispersive spectroscopy.

# usage: ./dataStitchR. -f "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/example_dataset" -b "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/example_dataset/SEM_images" -c "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|Os|SEM" -d "overview" -y "overview" -p TRUE -o "example" -n "example"
# usage Rscript dataStitchR.R -f "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/example_dataset" -b "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/example_dataset/SEM_images" -c "/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/dataStitcher/coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|Os|SEM" -d "overview" -y "overview" -p TRUE -o "example" -n "example"

message("
                                        #####                                    ######  
        #####     ##    #####    ##    #     #  #####  #  #####   ####   #    #  #     # 
        #    #   #  #     #     #  #   #          #    #    #    #    #  #    #  #     # 
        #    #  #    #    #    #    #   #####     #    #    #    #       ######  ######  
        #    #  ######    #    ######        #    #    #    #    #       #    #  #   #   
        #    #  #    #    #    #    #  #     #    #    #    #    #    #  #    #  #    #  
        #####   #    #    #    #    #   #####     #    #    #     ####   #    #  #     # 
        

        ")

message("DataStitchR was created by Caitlin Casar and is maintained at github.com/CaitlinCasar/dataStitchR.
        ")
message("DataStitchR stitches panoramic images of SEM images coupled to x-ray energy dispersive spectroscopy.
        ")
message("For help, run 'dataStitchR.R --help'.
        
        
        ")

suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(optparse))

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-f", "--file"), action="store", default=getwd(), type='character',
              help="Input parent directory with subdirectories of element xray data to be stitched. The element names should be abbreviated, i.e. 'Ca' for calcium."),
  make_option(c("-o", "--out"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Output file directory. This is where your x-ray raster brick and output figures will be saved."),
  make_option(c("-n", "--name"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Optional name for output files."),
  make_option(c("-b", "--base-images"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="SEM image file directory."),
  make_option(c("-c", "--coords"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Tab-delimited file of xy coordinates for each image. A third column should denote stitching positions that correspond to the file names for each image."),
  make_option(c("-u", "--use-positions"), action="store", default="-?(?<![Kα1||Kα1_2])\\d+", type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern to extract position IDs from each file name that corresponds to positions in the xy file. The default searches for numbers that appear after 'Kα1' or 'Kα2'. Numbers can include signs, i.e. -1 is acceptable."),
  make_option(c("-z", "--z-format"), action="store", default="*", type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern of x-ray image formats to select for stitching, i.e. '.tif'."),
  make_option(c("-m", "--make"), action="store", default="*", type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern of SEM image formats to select for stitching, i.e. '.tif'. You do not need to specify this unless you are generating a PDF output."),
  make_option(c("-a", "--all-exclude"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern of x-ray file directories to exclude from stitiching, i.e. the element your sample was coated with."),
  make_option(c("-d", "--drop"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern of files to exclude from x-ray data stitching."),
  make_option(c("-y", "--y-exclude"), action="store", default=NA, type='character',
              help="Optional regex pattern of files to exclude from SEM image stitiching. You do not need to specify this unless you are generating a PDF output."),
  make_option(c("-v", "--verbose"), action="store_true", default=TRUE,
              help="Print updates to console [default %default]."),
  make_option(c("-q", "--quiet"), action="store_false", dest="verbose",
              help="Do not print anything to the console."),
  make_option(c("-p", "--pdf"), action="store", default=FALSE,
              help="Generate PDF of x-ray brick colored by element superimposed on the SEM image, default is TRUE [default %default].")  
)
opt = parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list))


#load dependencies 
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(pacman))
pacman::p_load(raster, magick, tidyverse, rasterVis, ggnewscale, Hmisc, cowplot)

#create list all sub-directories within main directory
directories <- list.dirs(opt$f, full.names = T , recursive =F)
if(!is.na(opt$a)){
  directories <- directories[!str_detect(directories, opt$a)]
}


#set image coordinates
xy <- read_delim(opt$c, delim = "\t", col_types = cols())
positions <- xy %>%
  select(-x, -y)


# stitch xray images ------------------------------------------------------

#stitch xray images into panoramas and store in raster brick 
xray_brick_list <- list()
xray_data <- list()
for(j in 1:length(directories)){
  path = directories[j]
  files <- list.files(path, full.names = T, pattern = opt$z)
  if(!is.na(opt$d)){
    files <- files[!str_detect(files, opt$d)]
  }
  if(length(files) >0){
    xray_data[[j]] <- str_extract(path, "([^/]+$)")
    message(paste0("Stitching ", str_extract(xray_data[[j]], "([^/]+$)"), " data (element ", j, " of ", length(directories), ")..."))
    xy_id <- which(positions[[1]] %in% str_extract(files, opt$u))
    panorama <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(files)){
      message(paste0("Processing image ", i, " of ", length(files), "..."))
      image <- files[i] %>% image_read() %>% 
        image_quantize(colorspace = 'gray') %>% 
        image_equalize() 
      temp_file <- tempfile()
      image_write(image, path = temp_file, format = 'tiff')
      image <- raster(temp_file) %>%
        cut(breaks = c(-Inf, 150, Inf)) - 1
      image <- aggregate(image, fact=4)
      image_extent <- extent(matrix(c(xy$x[xy_id[i]], xy$x[xy_id[i]] + 1024, xy$y[xy_id[i]], xy$y[xy_id[i]]+704), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = T))
      image_raster <- setExtent(raster(nrows = 704, ncols = 1024), image_extent, keepres = F)
      values(image_raster) <- values(image)
      panorama[[xy_id[i]]] <- image_raster
    }
      empty_xy_id <- which(!positions[[1]] %in% str_extract(files, opt$u))
      if(length(empty_xy_id) > 0){
        for(k in 1:length(empty_xy_id)){
          empty_raster_extent <- extent(matrix(c(xy$x[empty_xy_id[k]], xy$x[empty_xy_id[k]] + 1024, xy$y[empty_xy_id[k]], xy$y[empty_xy_id[k]]+704), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = T))
          empty_raster <- setExtent(raster(nrows = 704, ncols = 1024), empty_raster_extent, keepres = F)
          values(empty_raster) <- 0
          panorama[[empty_xy_id[k]]] <- empty_raster
        }
      }
      panorama_merged <- do.call(merge, panorama)
      xray_brick_list[[j]] <- panorama_merged
  }
}

message("Stitching complete. Creating x-ray brick...")
xray_brick <- do.call(brick, xray_brick_list)
names(xray_brick) <- unlist(xray_data)
message("...complete.")

#write the brick 
message("Writing brick...")


if(!is.na(opt$o)){
  dir.create(opt$o)
  if(!is.na(opt$n)){
    out_brick <- writeRaster(xray_brick, paste0(opt$o, "/", opt$n,"_brick.grd"), overwrite=TRUE, format="raster")
    x <- writeRaster(xray_brick, paste0(opt$o, "/", opt$n,"_brick.tif"), overwrite=TRUE, format="GTiff",options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
  }else{
    out_brick <- writeRaster(xray_brick, path = opt$o, "brick.grd", overwrite=TRUE, format="raster")
    x <- writeRaster(xray_brick, path = opt$o, "brick.tif", overwrite=TRUE, format="GTiff",options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
  }
}else{
  if(!is.na(opt$n)){
    out_brick <- writeRaster(xray_brick, paste0(opt$n,"_brick.grd"), overwrite=TRUE, format="raster")
    x <- writeRaster(xray_brick, paste0(opt$n,"_brick.tif"), overwrite=TRUE, format="GTiff",options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
  }else{
    out_brick <- writeRaster(xray_brick, "brick.grd", overwrite=TRUE, format="raster")
    x <- writeRaster(xray_brick, "brick.tif", overwrite=TRUE, format="GTiff",options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
  }
}


message("...complete.")

#flush everything we don't need from memory
remove(list = c("x", "xray_brick_list", "xray_data", "empty_raster", "empty_raster_extent",
                "i", "j", "k", "path", "positions", "xy_id", 
                "panorama_merged", "panorama", "empty_xy_id", "files", "directories"))


# create base SEM image ---------------------------------------------------
if(opt$p){
  
if(!is.na(opt$b)){
  SEM_images <- list.files(opt$b, full.names = T, pattern = opt$m)
}else{
  message("Please provide a file path for your SEM images to stitch. For help, see 'dataStitchR.R --help.'")
  break
}

if(!is.na(opt$y)){
  SEM_images  <- SEM_images[!str_detect(SEM_images , opt$y)]
}
SEM_panorama <- list()

message("Stitching SEM images into panorama...")
for(i in 1:length(SEM_images)){
  image <- SEM_images[i] %>% image_read() %>%
    image_quantize(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
    image_equalize()
  temp_file <- tempfile()
  image_write(image, path = temp_file, format = 'tiff')
  image <- raster(temp_file)
  image_extent <- extent(matrix(c(xy$x[i], xy$x[i] + 1024, xy$y[i], xy$y[i]+704), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = T))
  image_raster <- setExtent(raster(nrows = 704, ncols = 1024), image_extent, keepres = F)
  values(image_raster) <- values(image)
  SEM_panorama[[i]] <- image_raster
}
SEM_panorama_merged <- do.call(merge, SEM_panorama)
message("...complete.")

#flush everything we don't need from memory
remove(list = c("SEM_panorama", "SEM_images", "image", "image_extent", "image_raster"))

#optinal plot to check if SEM image merge looks correct 
#plot(SEM_panorama_merged, col = gray.colors(10, start = 0.3, end = 0.9, gamma = 2.2, alpha = NULL))


# plot the data -----------------------------------------------------------

message("Generating plot...")
# Set color palette

#palette source: https://sciencenotes.org/molecule-atom-colors-cpk-colors/

element_colors <- c("#FFFFFF", "#D9FFFF", "#CC80FF", "#C2FF00", "#FFB5B5", "#909090", "#3050F8",
                    "#FF0D0D", "#90E050", "#B3E3F5", "#AB5CF2", "#8AFF00", "#BFA6A6", "#F0C8A0",
                    "#FF8000", "#FFFF30", "#1FF01F", "#80D1E3", "#8F40D4", "#3DFF00", "#E6E6E6",
                    "#BFC2C7", "#A6A6AB", "#8A99C7", "#9C7AC7", "#E06633", "#F090A0", "#50D050",
                    "#C88033", "#7D80B0", "#C28F8F", "#668F8F", "#BD80E3", "#FFA100", "#A62929",
                    "#5CB8D1", "#702EB0", "#00FF00", "#94FFFF", "#94E0E0", "#73C2C9", "#54B5B5",
                    "#3B9E9E", "#248F8F", "#0A7D8C", "#006985", "#C0C0C0", "#FFD98F", "#A67573",
                    "#668080", "#9E63B5", "#D47A00", "#940094", "#429EB0", "#57178F", "#00C900",
                    "#70D4FF", "#FFFFC7", "#D9FFC7", "#C7FFC7", "#A3FFC7", "#8FFFC7", "#61FFC7",
                    "#45FFC7", "#30FFC7", "#1FFFC7", "#00FF9C", "#00E675", "#00D452", "#00BF38",
                    "#00AB24", "#4DC2FF", "#4DA6FF", "#2194D6", "#267DAB", "#266696", "#175487",
                    "#D0D0E0", "#FFD123", "#B8B8D0", "#A6544D", "#575961", "#9E4FB5", "#AB5C00",
                    "#754F45", "#428296", "#420066", "#007D00", "#70ABFA", "#00BAFF", "#00A1FF",
                    "#008FFF", "#0080FF", "#006BFF", "#545CF2", "#785CE3", "#8A4FE3", "#A136D4",
                    "#B31FD4", "#B31FBA", "#B30DA6", "#BD0D87", "#C70066", "#CC0059", "#D1004F",
                    "#D90045", "#E00038", "#E6002E", "#EB0026")
names(element_colors) <- c("H",  "He", "Li", "Be", "B",  "C",  "N",  "O",  "F",  "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si",
                           "P",  "S",  "Cl", "Ar", "K",  "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V",  "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni",
                           "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y",  "Zr", "Nb", "Mo",
                           "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I",  "Xe", "Cs", "Ba",
                           "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb",
                           "Lu", "Hf", "Ta", "W",  "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po",
                           "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U",  "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf",
                           "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt")

xray_frame <- as.data.frame(xray_brick, xy=TRUE) 
xray_frame <- gather(xray_frame, element, value, colnames(xray_frame)[3]:colnames(xray_frame)[ncol(xray_frame)])



element_plotter<-function(coord_frame, brick, SEM_image, colors){
  p <-rasterVis::gplot(SEM_image) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'black', high = 'white') +
    ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()
  for(i in names(brick)){ 
    message(paste0("Adding ", names(brick[[i]]), " to plot..."))
    element_coords <- coord_frame %>%
      filter(element == names(brick[[i]]) & value!=0)
    p <- p+geom_raster(element_coords, mapping = aes(x, y, fill = element, alpha = value)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
      ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()
  }
  message("Writing plot...")
  suppressWarnings(print(p + 
                           coord_fixed() +
                           theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
                                 axis.text = element_blank(),
                                 legend.position = "none")))
}

element_plot <- element_plotter(xray_frame, xray_brick, SEM_panorama_merged, element_colors)

element_plot_legend <- data.frame(element = unique(xray_frame$element)) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(element, rowname, fill=element)) + 
  geom_bar(stat= "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = element_colors) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2)) +
  theme(legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
        legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 8))

element_plot_with_legend <- plot_grid(
  element_plot, 
  plot_grid(get_legend(element_plot_legend), 
            ncol = 1), 
  nrow = 2, 
  rel_heights = c(8,2)
)


# generate PDF ------------------------------------------------------------

if(!is.na(opt$n)){
  if(!is.na(opt$o)){
    pdf(paste0(opt$o, "/", opt$n, "_element_plot.pdf"),
        width = 13.33, 
        height = 7.5)
  }else{
    pdf(paste0(opt$n, "_element_plot.pdf"),
        width = 13.33, 
        height = 7.5)
  }
}else{
  if(!is.na(opt$o)){
    pdf(paste0(opt$o, "/", "element_plot.pdf"),
        width = 13.33, 
        height = 7.5)
  }else{
    pdf("element_plot.pdf",
        width = 13.33, 
        height = 7.5) 
  }
}


print(element_plot_with_legend)

dev.off()

message("...complete.")

remove(list = ls())

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not know Photoshop or R, so did it JavaScript:

```
const names = { // map from directory names to patterns (where "#" stands for position index) of names of images therein
 "SEM_images" : "pos# image.tif",
 "Al" : "Al Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Ba" : "Ba Lα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "C"  : "C Kα1_2 pos# map data.tif",
 "Ca" : "Ca Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Fe" : "Fe Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Hg" : "Hg Lα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Ir" : "Ir Lα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "K"  : "K Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Mg" : "Mg Kα1_2 pos# map data.tif",
 "Mn" : "Mn Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Na" : "Na Kα1_2 pos# map data.tif",
 "O"  : "O Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Os" : "Os Lα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "P"  : "P Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "S"  : "S Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Si" : "Si Kα1 pos# map data.tif",
 "Ti" : "Ti Kα1 pos# map data.tif"
}

const SCALE = 1/10 // scale of output images

const OVERLAP = 1.0 // minimum *tested* (horizontal) overlap of images relative to their width
const H_BOX = 0.1 // height of comparison box relative to height of images
const W_BOX = 0.1 // width  of comparison box relative to width  of images
const ADJUSTMENT = 0 // (vertical) adjustment of comparison box [pixels]

/* Merge images given:
 * dataset - dataset address as String
 * directory - directory name for images as String
 * pattern - pattern (where "#" stands for position index) of names of images in directory
 * pos_min - minimum position index of images as Number
 * pos_max - maximum position index of images as Number
 */
function Merge(dataset, directory, pos_min, pos_max) {
  if (dataset[dataset.length - 1] != "/") dataset += "/"
  const images = []
  for (let pos = pos_min; pos <= pos_max; ++pos) (images[pos - pos_min] = new Image).src = dataset + directory + "/" + names[directory].replace("#", pos)
  merge(images, dataset, pos_min, pos_max)
}

function Laplacian(imagedata) { // 5-point stencil approximation
  const data = imagedata.data
  const L = data.length/4
  const grayscale = new Float32Array(L)
  for (let i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
    const I = 4*i
    grayscale[i] = (data[I    ] + data[I + 1] + data[I + 2])/3
  }
  const Laplacian = new Float32Array(L)
  //const H = imagedata.height
  const Hm1 = imagedata.height - 1
  const W = imagedata.width
  const Wm1 = W - 1
  for (let r = 1; r < Hm1; ++r) {
    const R = r*W
    for (let c = 1; c < Wm1; ++c) {
      const i = R + c
      Laplacian[i] = grayscale[i - W] + grayscale[i + W] + grayscale[i - 1] + grayscale[i + 1] - 4*grayscale[i]
    }
  }
  for (let c = 1; c < Wm1; ++c) {
    //const i = c
    Laplacian[c] = grayscale[c + W] + grayscale[c - 1] + grayscale[c + 1] - 4*grayscale[c]
  }
  for (let c = 1; c < Wm1; ++c) {
    const i = Hm1*W + c
    Laplacian[i] = grayscale[i - W] + grayscale[i - 1] + grayscale[i + 1] - 4*grayscale[i]
  }
  for (let r = 1; r < Hm1; ++r) {
    const i = r*W
    Laplacian[i] = grayscale[i - W] + grayscale[i + W] + grayscale[i + 1] - 4*grayscale[i]
  }
  for (let r = 1; r < Hm1; ++r) {
    const i = r*W + Wm1
    Laplacian[i] = grayscale[i - W] + grayscale[i + W] + grayscale[i - 1] - 4*grayscale[i]
  }
  {
    const Lm1 = L - 1
    const LmW = L - W
    Laplacian[0  ] = grayscale[W      ] + grayscale[1      ] - 4*grayscale[0  ]
    Laplacian[W  ] = grayscale[2*W    ] + grayscale[Wm1    ] - 4*grayscale[W  ]
    Laplacian[LmW] = grayscale[LmW - W] + grayscale[LmW + 1] - 4*grayscale[LmW]
    Laplacian[Lm1] = grayscale[Lm1 - W] + grayscale[Lm1 - 1] - 4*grayscale[Lm1]
  }
  return Laplacian
}

function merge(images, dataset, pos_min, pos_max) {
  for (const image of images) if (!image.complete) {
    setTimeout(merge, 1000, images, dataset, pos_min, pos_max) // wait 1000ms = 1s
    return
  }
  let Row, Col
  const Coords = [[Row = 0, Col = 0]]
  let index = 0
  let image = images[index]
  const H = image.naturalHeight
  const W = image.naturalWidth
  if (W*H == 0) return []
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  canvas.height = H
  canvas.width  = W
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
  let prev = Laplacian(context.getImageData(0, 0, W, H))
  const length = images.length
  const h = Math.round(H_BOX*H)
  const Hmh = H - h
  const w = Math.round(W_BOX*W)
  const o = Math.max(Math.round((1 - OVERLAP)*W), w)
  const Wmw = W - w
  const row_offset = Math.round(Hmh/2) + ADJUSTMENT
  const offset = row_offset*W
  for (++index; index < length; ++index) {
    image = images[index]
    if (image.naturalHeight != H || image.naturalWidth != W) alert("Dimension mismatch: " + image.src)
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    const curr = Laplacian(context.getImageData(0, 0, W, H))
    let max = -1
    let row, col
    for (let r = 0; r < Hmh; ++r) {
      const R = r*W
      for (let c = o; c < Wmw; ++c) {
        let m = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
          const I = i*W
          const K = R + I + c
          const k = offset + I
          for (let j = 0; j < w; ++j) if (prev[K + j]*curr[k + j] > 0) ++m
        }
        if (m > max) {
          max = m
          row = r
          col = c
        }
      }
    }
    Coords[index] = [(Row += row - row_offset)/H, (Col += col)/W]
    prev = curr
  }
  Stitch(dataset, pos_min, pos_max, Coords)
}

function Stitch(dataset, pos_min, pos_max, Coords) {
  if (dataset[dataset.length - 1] != "/") dataset += "/"
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).innerText = `${dataset} :[${pos_min},${pos_max}] @${JSON.stringify(Coords)}`
  const tasks = []
  for (const directory in names) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("h2")).innerText = directory
    const images = []
    for (let pos = pos_min; pos <= pos_max; ++pos) (images[pos - pos_min] = new Image).src = dataset + directory + "/" + names[directory].replace("#", pos)
    const target = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"))
    target.height = 0
    target.width  = 0
    tasks.push([images, target])
  }
  process(tasks, Coords)
}

const ROW = 0
const COL = 1
function stitch(images, Coords) {
  let image
  let index
  for (index in images) {
    image = images[index]
    if (image.naturalHeight != 0 && image.naturalWidth != 0) break
  }
  const H = image.naturalHeight
  const W = image.naturalWidth
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  let r_min = 0
  let r_max = 0
  let c_min = 0
  let c_max = 0
  for (coords of Coords) {
    const r = coords[ROW]
    const c = coords[COL]
    if (r < r_min) r_min = r
    if (r > r_max) r_max = r
    if (c < c_min) c_min = c
    if (c > c_max) c_max = c
  }
  canvas.height = (r_max - r_min + 1)*H
  canvas.width  = (c_max - c_min + 1)*W
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  if (context == null) {
    let list = ""
    for (const image of images) list += "\n- " + image.src
    alert("Too large: stitching area required for:" + list)
    return
  }
  let coords = Coords[index]
  let row = (coords[ROW] - r_min)*H
  let col = (coords[COL] - c_min)*W
  context.drawImage(image, col, row)
  const length = images.length
  for (++index; index < length; ++index) {
    image = images[index]
    if (image.naturalHeight == 0 || image.naturalWidth == 0) continue
    if (image.naturalHeight != H || image.naturalWidth != W) alert("Dimension mismatch: " + image.src)
    coords = Coords[index]
    row = coords[ROW]*H
    col = coords[COL]*W
    context.drawImage(image, col, row)
  }
  return canvas.toDataURL()
}

function process(tasks, Coords) {
  const task = tasks.shift()
  const images = task[0]
  for (const image of images) if (!image.complete) {
    tasks.push(task)
    setTimeout(process, 1000, tasks, Coords) // wait 1000ms = 1s
    return
  }
  const target = task[1]
  target.src = stitch(images, Coords)
  target.onload = function () {
    this.height = SCALE*this.naturalHeight
    this.width  = SCALE*this.naturalWidth
    this.style = "border: solid black 1px"
  }
  if (tasks.length > 0) process(tasks, Coords)
}
```

To run, do something like:

```
Merge("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaitlinCasar/dataStitcher/master/example_dataset/", "SEM_images", -2, 4)
```

Example SEM_images with Fe overlay:
[image: SEM_images with Fe overlay]

Comment: You may need to disable cross-origin restrictions.